# How do you manually remove VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

The last VS Code update failed and hung at the little dialogue that says something like 'Preparing Update'. I had to close it manually. Once closed, it could not be restarted. I cannot reinstall it as it says I must remove the previous version first.

I have removed the program files folder. What else do I need to do to manually remove VS Code so I can reinstall it? I'm completely crippled without it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to `C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\` and delete the `Code` folder.